# Best way to measure transactions completed and conversion rate in Google Analytics - Big Query?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm new to google analytics and wanted to make sure I was doing this accurately. I have a sample table

[image]

Since I do not have too many rows (about 5000 rows only) I just created a pivot table in excel.

I counted how many visitors had an action type of "6" which is 'completed purchase' in GA terminology. I used visitId so that I can capture conversion rate based on all visits.

My result would look like this:

[image]

Is this the best way to do it? Am I missing anything?